# How do I reject initialized nested associations in Rails 5 prior to update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback, associations, nested-attributes

I have the following models

```
class Workout < ApplicationRecord
  before_save :remove_blank_measurables

  has_many :measurables
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :measurables, allow_destroy: true
end

class Measurable < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :workout
end
```

`Measurable` has a column "value".  When I create my form I do the following...

**Workouts#Edit**

```
def edit
  @workout.add_missing_measurable_types
end

def add_missing_measurable_types
  MeasurableType.workout_observations.each do |measurable_type|
    if self.doesnt_contain_measurable_type? measurable_type
      measurables.build(measurable_type_id: measurable_type.id, order_by: 1)
    end
  end
end
```

When `@workout.update(workout_params)` executes it attempts to insert records that have a null value for `value` on `Measurable`.  I have the code below to try and destroy the blank measurables before they're sent to be created, but I'm guessing they aren't part of my `each` loop due to only being initialized.

```
def remove_blank_measurables
  measurables.each do |measurable|
    if measurable.value.blank? || measurable.value.nil?
      measurables.destroy(measurable)
    end
  end
end
```

**Error**

```
TinyTds::Error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'value', table 'bane-development.dbo.measurables'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.: EXEC sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [measurables] ([measurable_type_id], [workout_id], [created_at], [updated_at], [import_key], [order_by]) OUTPUT INSERTED.[id] VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5)', N'@0 int, @1 int, @2 datetime, @3 datetime, @4 int, @5 int', @0 = 10, @1 = 689441, @2 = '08-10-2018 16:08:18.609', @3 = '08-10-2018 16:08:18.609', @4 = -1, @5 = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reject unsuitable `:measurables` attributes rather than records which are not in the scope at that moment. `:accepts_nested_attributes_for` method has the `:reject_if` option for this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :measurables, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['value'].blank? }
```

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for